# Emulate PTY and output line-flushed stream

Tags: linux, shell, unix, output-buffering, tty

I'm looking for a way to trick a Linux program into thinking that it is connected to TTY so that output is line-buffered instead of block-buffered.

When I call the program directly inside the terminal emulator it behaves correctly, but if I pipe its output to `while read line; do ...; done` or `cat` it doesn't.

Basically I would like to end up with something like this:

```
exec "${some_strange_wrapper}" "${some_program}" | while read line;
do
    # Do something...
done
```

Answer (score 3):

While considering more things to write in my question, I found the answer!

Use `socat`! Its an external program that can establish a lot of different kinds of connection between different types of file descriptions.

In this case however, it may be used like this:

```
socat EXEC:"${some_program}",pty stdout
```

Thanks to everybody out there, checking if this question needs answering! (Although it isn't necessary in this case anymore...) :-)

Comment: +1 self-answers are good for SO